# SQL getting text from brackets

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I will try to explain my problem, as best as I can.

I am working on a SSIS project (business intelligence). In one data flow, I need to extract text from brackets.

In the base database, I have a column (in a table) where the values are different from each other:

```
aaa(bbb ccc, ddd)
aaa(bbbb ccc, ddd)
aaa(bb)
```

and so on.

I need to extract the text from brackets, to the new database in different columns.

So it would look something like this

```
col1  col2  col3
bbb   ccc   ddd
```

Is there any suggestions how to make this work in data flow. The base database is a mess, as u can see, and I am trying to make it a bit more organized.

Comment: is the beginning always "aaa("? If not: What should be done with this information? btw: Congrats to your decision to clean up your db. This is a wise decision :-)

Comment: The first row is split into 3 columns. What about the last two rows? What is the maximum amount of entities you expect to find between brackets?

Comment: No it has other values also. The table shows if in use, warehouse, repairing and so on. In the brackets its sometimes shows location, name and adres. 
Right now i need info about the warehouse. So i can point that the beginning is always the same. But the info in brackets is different as u can see:
I have tryied usin LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status.name, '(', - 1), 3) But then when i have only bracket value with bbbb I won get the last letter. 

Maximum amount of things is 3.

It is not my database. I am on internship and trying to fix  their mess.

Comment: Just looked over the database. There is only one value where there is only aaa(bbb). But others look like this (bbb ccc, ddd). There is always coma after ccc. Values in the brackets differ in lenght.

Answer (score 1):

When you change `(` and  you can split like this:

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0b3aa/21/0)**

```
    ;WITH to_xml(orig,col)
AS(
 SELECT t, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t, '(', ','), ' ', ','), ')', '')
FROM tab
)
 ,Split_Names (orig, col, xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT orig,
    col,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Vals><Val>'  
    + REPLACE(col,',', '</Val><Val>') + '</Val></Vals>') AS xmlname
      FROM to_xml
)
SELECT  
 orig,
 xmlname.value('/Vals[1]/Val[1]','varchar(100)') AS col1,    
 xmlname.value('/Vals[1]/Val[2]','varchar(100)') AS col2,
 xmlname.value('/Vals[1]/Val[3]','varchar(100)') AS col3,
 xmlname.value('/Vals[1]/Val[4]','varchar(100)') AS col4
 FROM Split_Names
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will break up your strings to any depth. First I split this into the Leading part and the parts within the bracket, afterwards I split the internal parts. Adapt this to your needs:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourConcatColumn VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('aaa(bbb ccc ddd)')
,('aaa(bbbb ccc ddd)')
,('aaa(bbb ddd)')
,('aaa(bb)');

WITH TwoParts(Inx, Divided) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Inx
          ,CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(tbl.YourConcatColumn,')',''),'(','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML)
    FROM @tbl AS tbl 
)
,InternalParts(Inx, LeadingPart,InternalParts) AS
(
    SELECT TwoParts.Inx
          ,TwoParts.Divided.value('/root[1]/r[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(TwoParts.Divided.value('/root[1]/r[2]','varchar(max)'),' ','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) 
    FROM TwoParts
)
SELECT Inx
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Inx ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS InternalInx
      ,InternalParts.LeadingPart
      ,Parts.Part.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM InternalParts
CROSS APPLY InternalParts.InternalParts.nodes('/root/r') AS Parts(Part)
```

Comment: I just added the column InternalInx which allows you to address the position of a part within the brackets. The result could be tranformed into a "real" 1:many related table structure.